# Using theater lamp for heating

Tags: energy, electricity, soft-question

I'm asking myself a question about how to warm my house up, and the efficiency of such a thing :

I live in a theater, and we got plenty of 1000W lighting fixture, mostly Tungsten incandescence things, like [PAR 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_aluminized_reflector_light).
According to my research on the web, the energy efficiency of those thing is [between 3% and 5%.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Efficacy.2C_efficiency.2C_and_environmental_impact)
So, if I assume that the rest 95%+ is wasted on heating, that might means they are not far away from typical heaters. Bonus point is, it gives me some light.

But I'm not sure it really works that way.

So the question is : where is really all the wasted energy of a tungsten incandescence fixture really spend on ?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Welcome to Physics.SE, btw! Just so you know, questions where the most thorough and correct answer can potentially be "Yes." are usually off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Jim : I modified the question so it is open, and people can start explaining how the energy efficiency works, and where the wasted energy goes.

Comment: This question in various guises has been asked many times.  Part of the answer is: what's cheaper in your area, electricity or oil or gas (per obtainable BTU)?  And yes it's true that all power ends up as heat sooner or later, but there's the question of even distribution, loss due to absorption into things like walls, and risk of fire due to very hot source.  And so on.

Comment: @BrandonEnright : Right, the answer I'm looking for is in that question. Got my answer, thank you